# Use ifream for read and fill the site forms

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Can use an iframe then read and fill the forms of the iframe? If no what other options do I have. If yes please explain a simple way

I need to use an iframe from another domain (for example Google.com iframe) then fill the forms (search input in Google and then submit form)

If there is any options that I can to this in JavaScript its very nice

For example I could use the Dom content of iframe like this

```
document.getelementbyid("main").innerhtml="text";
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i need to use an ifream then read the Dom content of cross-domain ifream